# The syntax of the command is incorrect.?

Tags: command-line

This is my code for a project im working on

```
@echo off
set %adjective1%=red            
set %adjective2%=big          
echo Its so %adjective1% and %adjective2%.         
pause
```

heres the response i get from it in batch

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.       
The syntax of the command is incorrect.         
Its so  and .        
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm not sure why it does this, anyone know why?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Remove the `@echo off` and you will see which lines cause which errors

Comment: @Burgi im making a program that generates a story from a list of adjectives, verbs, nouns and a bunch of other things

Answer (score 4):

The `set` command does not want `%` in front and behind the variable names.

Just use

```
set adjective2=big
```

You still need the `%` when you *use* the variables but as you are `set`ing environment variables you don't need them. The `set` command knows that you want to set an environment variable and just wants you to specify a name and value.

The `set` command is taking a name of a variable to set but by putting `%` around the name you are effectively trying to *use* the environment variable. At this point it has no value and your `set` effectively becomes

```
set =red
```

Which is invalid. You cannot set `<blank>` to "red"

% on either side means use this environment variable. `Set` does not want to *use* the variable.